# Scrape RSelenium site with tabs where Inspector Gadget fails

Tags: r, rselenium

This site has a table (Guaranteed Investment Certificate - Long-Term and Compound Interest) that appears after clicking a tab (Non-cashable GICs).

My plan is to find the tab by id click on it and then grab the HTML source.
Then, I usually use `read_html` and `html_nodes` to get closer to the items I'm searching for. In this case, the rates for Non-registered and Registered (TFSA, RSP, RIF, RESP).

However, Inspector Gadget with Chrome freezes on the site so I am unsure as to what css selector to use. Any ideas on how to get the rates for the Guaranteed Investment Certificate - Long-Term and Compound Interest table?

```
# TD GIC scrape - FAIL
remDr$navigate("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/saving-investing/gic-rates-canada/")

# Find element, click element and then get source
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "Tab_non-cashable")
webElem$clickElement()
html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

read_html(html) %>% # parse HTML
  html_nodes("td-complex-chart") 

# {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. But from what I understood, you want to scrape a table that is not visible at first.
I quickly went to the page and all the tables withint tabs are in the HTML code, so you don't need selenium to click on that tab, you just need to request the HTML, and then scrape the code to get your information.
Insted of using Inspector Gadget, use the Inspect function or look into the code by typing ctrl + u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below my solution:

```
library(Rselenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port = 4567L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/saving-investing/gic-rates-canada/")
webElem <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="Tab_non-cashable"]')
webElem$clickElement()
```

and after you can take your table.

Below an idea about how to take the **Guaranteed Investment Certificate - Long-Term and Simple Interest**

```
webElem <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css selector", 'section.ng-scope:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(1)')
webElem$getElementText()
[[1]]
[1] "Guaranteed Investment Certificate - Long-Term and Simple Interest\nTerm\nNon-registered and Registered (TFSA, RSP, RIF, RESP)\n1 year\n0.45%\n2 years\n0.50%\n3 years\n0.60%\n4 years\n0.70%\n5 years\n0.85%"
```

When you can I suggest you to use the `xpath` to individual the part that you need.